# jQuery reset a single table during onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as follows. How to reset the table using jQuery to its original state during on change(with all th,tds). Not to reload the entire page because I have another tables also. I tried with dataTables but it adds search filters and paginations unnecessarily

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="t01">
  <thead style="text-align:center">
     <tr>
        <th class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center">Dxx</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Rxx/Unit</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Txxx</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Pxxx</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th>Full</th>
        <td id="fp" style="text-align:right">0</td>
        <td id="fr" style="text-align:center">0</td>
        <td>
          <div style="float:left">$</div>
          <div style="float:right" id="fpT">0.00</div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th >Fractional</th>
        <td id="fr" style="text-align:right">0</td>
        <td id="frN" style="text-align:center">0</td>
        <td>
          <div style="float:left">$</div>
          <div id="frT" style="float:right">0.00</div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th >Premium</th>
        <td id="pRate" style="text-align:right">0</td>
        <td id="pNos"  style="text-align:center">0%</td>
        <td>
          <div style="float:left">$</div>
          <div id="pTotal" style="float:right">0.00</div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="active">
        <th>Premium Discount</th>
        <td style="text-align:right" id="premium-discount-rate">0</td>
        <td  style="text-align:center">
        <select id="premium-disc-list">
           <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="float:left">$</div>
          <div style="float:right" id="premium-discount-total">0.00</div>
        </td>
        </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var table = $('#t01').dataTable();
//table.clear().draw();

//table.fnClearTable();
//table.fnDraw();
//table.fnDestroy();
//table.fnDraw();
```

Comment: You can remove/hide paginations in case you are not required in Datatable..

Comment: You can do it following way:

$('#Grid_Id').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": false
            });

Comment: Where is the JavaScript/jQuery codes?

Comment: @Dilip - All my td contents are removed if I use dataTable and In some of my rows are realigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 options in my mind:

1) You can mark all the elements that could be reset with some 'resetable' class and add `data-original-val` property, and once you decide to reset it do something like that:

```
$('.resetable','#t01').each(function(){
     var originalVal = $(this).data('original-val');
     $(this).html(originalVal);
})
```

2) Render another copy of the table inside `type="text/html"` script like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="t01-original">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="t01">
  <thead style="text-align:center">
     <tr>
        <th class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center">Dxx</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Rxx/Unit</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Txxx</th>
        <th class="col-md-2" style="text-align:center">Pxxx</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
 </table>
</script>
```

this way all the content of the script tag won't be parsed and you won't have duplicate id issues. On the reset simply replace the content of the table with the one from the script:

```
//t01-container is the id of div that wraps the table:

$( '#t01-container').html($('#t01-original').html());
```

Comment: but you need the source for clone. Also clone doesn't behave well with ids

Comment: My be before `initializing` the `.dataTable` ?

Comment: This solution works not only for `.dataTable` but for simple html table as well

Comment: @AlexArt. - What is original-val in first example

Comment: it should hold the original value of the element for example `<td id="fp" style="text-align:right" data-original-val="5">5</td>`. if user changes the value to 1, the `td` will look like: `<td id="fp" style="text-align:right" data-original-val="5">1</td>` so you will be able to reset the value because data-original-val still holds a 5

Comment: @AlexArt. - Here original value refers the entire table values? How to bring that in .data(?)

Comment: As I said each element that could be changed and reset should have its own `data-original-val`. in order to reset the table you are looping through all the `.resetable` elements

Comment: I would prefer the second option

Comment: @AlexArt. - Thanks for the idea